# Trying a tiny winy 3D classes for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, 3d

Ok,

I'm trying to save some time creating some generic classes to draw objects in the 3D space.

I created a Object3D class with the properties x, y, and z.

The thumbnail3D is a "son" of Object3D using inheritance. Vertex3D is a struct with a GLfloat for every coord.

The problem is when I try to compile the method initWithPosition:( Vertex3D *)vertex, and the error is:

**Request for member 'x' in something not structure or union.
Request for member 'y' in something not structure or union.
Request for member 'z' in something not structure or union.**

But, the structure is on the import...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>

@interface Object3D : NSObject 
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
}

@property  GLfloat x;
@property  GLfloat y;
@property  GLfloat z;

-(void) render;

@end
```

The render is still hardcoded

```
#import "Thumbnail3D.h"
#import "ConstantsAndMacros.h"
#import "OpenGLCommon.h"

@implementation Thumbnail3D

@synthesize width;
@synthesize height;

-(void)render
{
    Triangle3D  triangle[2];
    triangle[0].v1 = Vertex3DMake(0.0, 1.0, -3.0);
    triangle[0].v2 = Vertex3DMake(1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    triangle[0].v3 = Vertex3DMake(-1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    triangle[1].v1 = Vertex3DMake(-1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    triangle[1].v2 = Vertex3DMake(1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    triangle[1].v3 = Vertex3DMake(0.0, -1.0, -3.0);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &triangle);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

-(void)initWithPosition:(Vertex3D *)vertex
{
    x = vertex.x;
    y = vertex.y;
    z = vertex.z;
}

@end
```

Comment: Well, on the one hand I like to this myself because I think is the fastest way to learn but on the other hand, maybe is a good little engine out there I can use ;)

Comment: The code sample is not clear. Is thumbnail3D a subclass of Object3D or is Vertex3D? What is Vertex3D?

Comment: The thumbnail3D is a "son" of Object3D using inheritance.

Vertex3D is a struct with a GLfloat for every coord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I read this part

> Vertex3D is a struct with a GLfloat for every coord.

I think you should write

```
-(void)initWithPosition:(Vertex3D *)vertex
{
  x = vertex->x;
  y = vertex->y;
  z = vertex->z;
}
```

...as vertex then is a plain-old pointer to a C struct

Comment: Yep, a `Vertex3d*` is in fact not a structure or a union — it's a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to pass Object3D into the init function?

I dont know what Vertex3D is..

Or, is that supposed to be the implementation for Object3D? In which case you need to have

```
@implementation Object3D
```

at the start.

And you should probably

```
@synthesize x
@synthesize y
@synthesize z
```

instead of width, height..

Answer (score 0):

The error...

> Request for member 'x' in something
>   not structure or union.

... means that something has gone wrong in the definition of a structure, union or class. Either, (1) the Vertex3D struct was not defined properly or (2) the definition was not included properly in the `Thumbnail3D` class.